# WordPress plugin document title parts not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin that uses add_filter to change the title of the page.
In an empty wordpress website it just works fine. But I have two other websites where I want to use my plugin, but for some reason there it will not work at all.

```
function hooks() {
    if(get_query_var('car_id') != "") {
        add_action('wp_head', 'fillHead');
        add_filter('document_title_parts', 'addTitle', PHP_INT_MAX);
    }
    add_shortcode('auto', 'showCar');
}
```

I tried to deactivate some plugins and the theme etc. But nothing seems to work. I don't know where the title is changed. Is there a way to see what is happening in wp_head() or why this code is not executed at the right time?

**EDIT**
In the header.php there is a bit of code that makes the title. If I delete this part it is still not working. It will make the url as the title.
But how can i overrule this  tag in my plugin?

Comment: the second argument of add_shortcode should be hooks and not showCar

Comment: That's just fine. its the function that the shortcode will execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a way to get it to work.
In the theme there is a header-details.php. I deleted everything between the  tags and only added the following:

```
<?=wp_title( '|', true, 'right' )?>
```

Then to the plugin I used the filter wp_title instead of document_title_parts.

It works for now but I will still have to test this on other sites

Answer (score 2):

Your plugin code is most likely going to run before the theme code and will run before anything is added to the hook. You will need to the code that processes the file inclusion to some other hook that runs after all of the plugins load, like [after_setup_theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme)

[This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence) is the wordpress loading sequence?

Comment: The after_setup_theme is not working for me but thanks for the loading sequence